# Loop over files returned from find?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to piece together a script that recursively finds all the `*.plist` files in a directory and then operates on them. The script is below, but its producing unexpected results.

The expected result is each filename is printed like:

```
File: XXX
File: YYY
File: ZZZ
```

The problem is the `for file in "$FILES"` is ***not*** sending one file at a time. Rather, its sending in the whole list at once (`FILES` was gathered using `find`), so I'm getting output like:

```
File: XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

The real output is shown below, but the above is an accurate digest of it.

How do I make the shell loop over the individual files in the variable `FILES`?

---

```
#! /bin/sh

do_test_file() {
  FILE="$1"
  echo "File: $FILE"
  # echo `ls -al "$FILE"`
  echo ""
}

do_test_dir() {
  DIR="$1"
  FILES=`find "$DIR" -name "*.plist" 2>/dev/null`

  for file in "$FILES"
  do

    if [ ! -d "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ]; then
      do_test_file "$file"
    fi

  done
}

########################################

ARG="$1"
if [ -z "$ARG" ]; then
  echo "Please invoke with a file or directory to search"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -d "$ARG" ]; then
  do_test_dir "$ARG"
else
  do_test_file "$ARG"
fi
```

---

```
$ ./plist-dump.sh .

File: ./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist
./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/iTunesMetadata.plist
./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/ResourceRules.plist
./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/Info.plist
./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/Settings.bundle/Root.plist
./916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/SC_Info/Manifest.plist
```

Comment: You created variable `FILES` with single value - the whole output from `find`. You should use arrays instead like `FILES=($(find ...))` or rearrange the script completely.

Comment: @jimmij - Maybe I should back up (I'm not a shell expert). How do I tell the shell the newline is a delimiter for `for each` since that's what `find` uses?

Comment: This is the wrong approach entirely. Use `-exec`.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the -exec function in find itself:

```
find "${DIR}" -name "*.plist" -type f -exec echo "do some stuff to " {} \;
```

Breaking that down:

- -type tests to ensure that the thing it found is a file
- -exec executes the code....
- echo "do some stuff "
- {}  represents the file being operated on during this iteration
- \;   closes the code statement and returns for next iteration

This might simplify your script.

Comment: I thought that `do_test_file` bit must be a separate script at first and only just now noticed the shell function definition at top. It's what confused me about the `echo` here. Still, this could be a whole lot faster *(and protect it from possible breakage related to `echo`)* = like... `find ... -exec printf 'File: %s\n' {} +`

Answer (score 4):

You created variable FILES with single value - the whole output from find. One solution is to use arrays instead, like:

```
FILES=($(find . -name "*.txt" 2>/dev/null))
```

and later on

```
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
```

Note that you should rather use `$()` for command substitution instead of backticks ``.

Comment: This breaks on any files containing spaces or newlines in the name.

Comment: I had to change from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. Otherwise, `Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")`.